# How do I apply a smoothing filter with dask

Tags: python, dask

I have a 2 dimensional array, I would like to do a 2 dimensional convolution with a kernel, for example a simple flat square matrix.

See for example: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/zonca/f0d819048ef7318eff944396b71af1c4

Is there a way to run this multithreaded with `dask`?

Comment: can you please add more details about your question here? For future searches, It's better if the question is self-contained instead of being explained in an external notebook, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [map_overlap](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.Array.map_overlap) method may do what you want.  It allows you to map a function over chunks of your array where those chunks have been pre-buffered with an overlapping region from nearby chunks.

Something like the following might be a good start:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.random.normal(10, 1, size=(1000, 1000))

In [3]: from scipy.signal import convolve2d

In [4]: import dask.array as da
In [5]: d = da.from_array(x, chunks=(500, 500))

In [6]: filt = np.ones((8, 8))

In [7]: d.map_overlap(convolve2d, in2=filt, depth=8)
Out[7]: dask.array<trim-de..., shape=(1000, 1000), dtype=None, chunksize=(500, 500)>
```

Although beware that the filter you've provided both smooths and amplifies.  You might also need to play with the trimming in convolve2d.